# UuidToString on WinRT

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I have a C++ WinRT (Windows Phone) project and need to work with UUIDs.

I have code like this:

```
UUID vol_uuid;
CoCreateGuid(&vol_uuid);
RPC_WSTR    volbuf[256];
UuidToString(&vol_uuid, volbuf);
```

However, Visual Studio gives me a `UuidToString undefined` error on the last line. (CoCreateGuid seems OK).
I did include `<rpc.h>` but the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states this function is desktop only.

Is there any other library function to convert the UUID to a string?

Comment: Are you working on an app that you plan to release in the store, or an enterprise app? You could probably modify header files to grant yourself access to UuidToString, but the store would flag you for accessing a restricted api

Comment: @robwirving No, it needs to be published to the store...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use StringFromGUID2, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms683893.aspx, which is on the whitelist of Win32 APIs for Windows Store Apps.

The full list of these APIs, where you also find CoGreatGuid, is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn424765.aspx.